# Java 8: How to list files that don't match pattern using regex

Tags: java, regex, loops, io, filenames

For some reason, my code will print ALL files when I want it to only print out the files that DONT match my regex pattern.. I need it to print out the files that dont match the pattern because I dont know all the possible inconsistencies there are in the file naming. I checked my regex pattern on regex101 and it is correct. I am not a coder, but I am a psychology student working on a mass database.

Ive tried making Pattern into a list pattern, and I tried putting patternList.matcher(file.getName()) into like its own Matcher variable.

```
    private static void checkFolder(File root, Pattern patternList) {
        for(File file : root.listFiles())

        if(file.isFile()){

            if(patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
                checkFolder(file, patternList);
            else 
                System.out.println(file); //print if it does not match
        }
```

For example, If my code looks at these file names:

- 95F Front Anger.BW
- 95F.Front.Anger.C.Micro
- 95F.Front.Fear.C.Micro
- 95F.Front.Frown.BW

And my regex is this:

```
    Pattern patternList = Pattern.compile("((\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)"
    +"\\.(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C)))|"
    +"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)\\.(Neutral|Smile)\\."
    +"(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C))|"
    +"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\\.(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW))")
```

My code should only print out 95F Front Anger.BW, because it has whitespaces instead of dots, but my code still prints out all four filenames.

I also tried doing this:

```
    private static void checkFolder(File root, Pattern patternList) {
    for(File file : root.listFiles())

        if(file.isFile()){

            if(patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches()){
                 checkFolder(file, patternList);  //call checkfolder if the filename matches the pattern

            }
            else if(!patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
            {
               System.out.println(file); //print the file that doesnt match the regex
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the pattern, and what is the for loop supposed to do? From what I can tell, you have a for loop that iterates through a directory, and if it's a file and matches the regex, calls checkFolder on the file.

Comment: the for loop is supposed to get through all the files from the given directory

Comment: Is it supposed to be iterative and check subdirectories or no?

Comment: well when i look at it, my code isn't doing that, but I would like it to check subdirectories too.

Comment: Well, to handle the root of the problem, you should explain to us what you are trying to match and example positive and negative matches.

Comment: Have you considered the file extension in the regex pattern? File.getName() will return the extension also, e.g. sample.txt, sample.xlsx etc.

Comment: These files are jpgs of people with different facial expressions. We have a specific way of labeling the photos, however, interns throughout the years would name them in different ways. My regex is the correct pattern that the files should be named.

Comment: just updated my post

Comment: Simply using `!` not? E.g. `if(!patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
                    System.out.println(file);`

Comment: tried that. it might be my regex..

Comment: @wp78de If pattern is correct negating will be enough, it would be : `if(!patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
                checkFolder(file, patternList);
            else 
                System.out.println(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I'm guessing you want something like this, assuming you are only looking for *files* that match the pattern:

```
private static void checkFolder(File dir, Pattern patternList) {
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            // only check pattern against files not directories
            if(!patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
                System.out.println(file);
        } else {
            // recurse into any/all sub-directories
            checkFolder(file, patternList);
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to do something with the results other than just print them, you could concatenate into a List.

(and yes, to be pedantically complete, recursion is not the best solution if you expect to traverse deep file system paths, this can be changed into looping with a stack at the cost of extra complexity)

Comment: thank you. its so weird though, tried negating it and I'm still getting incorrect results :/

Comment: Why you moved the `System.out.println(file);` after negating it? I think you just need to negate  and it should work if pattern is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression works just fine, you might just want to replace `\.` with something like:

```
(?:\.|\s+)
```

or

```
\s*\.?
```

or

```
[.\s]
```

or

```
[. ]
```

where necessary, and it might work OK.

```
((\d{1,3}([FM])(?:\.|\s+)(Front|Profile|Right)(?:\.|\s+)(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)(?:\.|\s+)(BW\.Micro|BW|C\.Micro|C)))|(\d{1,3}(F|M)\.(Front|Profile|Right)\.(Neutral|Smile)\.(C\.Micro|C|BW\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\.(BW\.Micro|BW|C\.Micro|C))|(\d{1,3}(F|M)\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\.(C\.Micro|C|BW\.Micro|BW))
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "((\\d{1,3}([FM])(?:\\.|\\s*)(Front|Profile|Right)(?:\\.|\\s*)(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)(?:\\.|\\s*)(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C)))|(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)\\.(Neutral|Smile)\\.(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C))|(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\\.(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW))";
final String string = "95F    Front   Anger   BW\n"
     + "95F Front Anger BW\n"
     + "95F Front Anger.BW\n"
     + "95F.Front.Anger.C.Micro\n"
     + "95F.Front.Fear.C.Micro\n"
     + "95F.Front.Frown.BW";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7rFpuJ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7rFpuJ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

Also, maybe if we would design our expression(s) in this fashion,

```
^(\d{1,3})\s*([FM])\s*\.?(\w+)\s*\.?(\w+)\s*\.?(\w+\.\w+|\w+)\s*$
```

that would be maybe OK too, not sure though.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/yBGPl6/1/)

---

To negate the pattern, we can try:

```
^(?!(?:((\d{1,3}([FM])\.(Front|Profile|Right)\.(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)\.(BW\.Micro|BW|C\.Micro|C)))|(\d{1,3}(F|M)\.(Front|Profile|Right)\.(Neutral|Smile)\.(C\.Micro|C|BW\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\.(BW\.Micro|BW|C\.Micro|C))|(\d{1,3}(F|M)\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\.(C\.Micro|C|BW\.Micro|BW)))).*$
```

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/i2FULh/1/)

---

Or a bit more simplified, maybe, if that be OK:

#### [DEMO 4](https://regex101.com/r/ijbvmC/1/)

Comment: thanks, but my goal is to print files that dont match the pattern. unfortunately i dont know all the different types of inconsistencies in the file naming there are

Comment: by how im looking at your code, youre trying to do direct matches

Comment: yes kind of like that, but looking for specific words instead of any word, just like how my expression is. i think an if-statement might be easier for me